# Why there isn't any default selected value for the dropdown, in the angular form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

Below is the template

```
<form #testScript="ngForm">
  <div class="channel-container">
    <div
      class="channel"
      *ngFor="
        let currentChannel of members;
        let ch_index = index
      "
    >
      <select
        class="form-select"
        [(ngModel)]="currentChannel.selectedValue"
        name="ddd"
      >
        <option
          *ngFor="let testFormat of currentChannel.options"
          [ngValue]="testFormat"
        >
          {{testFormat.val}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And .ts file for this is in below.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'test-app';
  members:any = [];
  ngOnInit(){
    
    this.members.push({options:[{id:1,val:'ok'},{id:2,val:'kk'}],selectedValue:undefined});
    this.members[0].selectedValue = this.members[0].options[1];

    this.members.push({options:[{id:1,val:'ok'},{id:2,val:'kk'}],selectedValue:undefined});
    this.members[1].selectedValue = this.members[1].options[1];
  }
}
```

And the respose was something like this.
[Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jlTG.png)

I don't understand, as I keep on adding more dropdown only the last dropdown, rendered with default value. All the previous dropdown gets reseted somehow.

I noticed if I use the html code that's inside the  element without the form element, it renders as usual.

```
<div class="channel-container">
    <div
      class="channel"
      *ngFor="
        let currentChannel of members;
        let ch_index = index
      "
    >
      <select
        class="form-select"
        [(ngModel)]="currentChannel.selectedValue"
        name="ddd"
      >
        <option
          *ngFor="let testFormat of currentChannel.options"
          [ngValue]="testFormat"
        >
          {{testFormat.val}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEOab.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because of the way Angular handles Forms. When using a form in Angular, it is recommended to have a unique name attribute for each form control (such as a select dropdown) within the form. In this case, all the select dropdowns have the same name attribute value of "ddd". This causes the form to treat all the select dropdowns as a single form control, hence overwriting the selected value of previous dropdowns.

I completely forgot about it.